# Why is my PDO not working?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am starting to use PDO and I successfully connected to MySQL using PDO. However, when I try to SELECT stuff from my DB, nothing happens. Nothing is echoed. (even though I have records in that table, and the column username exists) No error in my PHP log.

I am using MAMP and all PDO components seem to be working in phpinfo() (since I was able to connect to db in the first place)

Please let me know what could have gone wrong. Thanks a lot

```
    <?php
    try 
    {
        $connection = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname:my_db','my_username',
                              'xxxxxxx');   


            $stmt=$connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM users");
            $stmt->execute();

            while ($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){

                echo $row->username;
            }

    }

    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        echo "There was an error connecting to the database";
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: Shame on your for having error reporting (or display_errors) off! ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to tell PDO that you want it to throw exceptions:

```
$connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Following your comment below, it is apparent that your DSN is incorrect.  It should be:

```
$connection = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=my_db','my_username','xxxxxxx');
```

Note that the syntax is `dbname=` rather than `dbname:` (which you had originally).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I get this: `There was an error connecting to the databaseexception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected' in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/myproject/trypdo.php:8 Stack trace: #0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/myproject/trypdo.php(8): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main}`. I use the same credential as with mysql_connect. It don't understand why this is happening.

Comment: @alexx0186: Your DSN is incorrect.  See my updated answer above.

Comment: Oh... Thanks for that. It's weird that the catch section wasn't executed then. I assume `setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` is only for development? Thanks for your help

Comment: `setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION)` could be for production too, so long as you're using `try {} catch {}` (otherwise SQL errors which could disclose useful information to an attacker might get leaked).

Comment: Do you mean that with this setAttribute statement, the errors will only be visible on the log, thus not to the user/attacker? Thanks for your help

Comment: @alexx0186: Read [the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php) for further info.

Answer (score 3):

First, get your query out of your PDO connection segment...

```
<?php
try 
{
    $connection = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname:my_db','my_username',
                          'xxxxxxx');
}

catch(Exception $e)
{
    echo "There was an error connecting to the database";
}
?>
```

Then, do it.

```
<?php
$SQL = 'SELECT * FROM users';
foreach($connection->query($SQL) as $row){
    print $row['username'] . "\n".'<br />';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not ask PHP?

```
catch(Exception $e)
{
    die($e);
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. The catch is not triggered in my case. Something is wrong with the try section. Regards

Comment: what if you try to dump $row inside while loop?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your either don't have data in that table or have an error:

Try to add this code after `$stmt->execute();`:

```
$arr = $sth->errorInfo();
print_r($arr);
```